# How to use angular-qrcode Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, qr-code

(As suggested by George Stocker in the comments I've edited this question so that it is now about angular-qrcode instead of QRCode.js.)

I'm trying to use [angular-qrcode](https://github.com/monospaced/angular-qrcode) to display qr-codes in Angular, but I can't get it to work. I'm currently simply trying this code as described in [the readme](https://github.com/monospaced/angular-qrcode/blob/master/README.md):

```
<qrcode data="string"></qrcode>
```

Unfortunatel it doesn't do anything. I don't get any error, but I don't see any qr-image either.

To give a working example I forked the [angular-phonecat tutorial here](https://github.com/kramer65/angular-phonecat) and tried using angular-qrcode in that code ([commit here](https://github.com/kramer65/angular-phonecat/commit/6e686f49827c0992378d611bab68517c7bf3b6b0)).

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong trying to use angular-qrcode? All tips are welcome!

Comment: One of the things that helps us answer your question is you taking the time to write code that reproduces the issue and placing it  in your question. By just posting a link, we won't be able to see your code if that link dies or goes down. Also, putting your code into your question forces you to take the time to reduce the cruft and make it easy for us to follow.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker - I edited my question and added the code that I'm currently trying (which is only one line). Unfortunately it doesn't produce the desired result (a qr-code) but it doesn't give an error either. It just doesn't display anything. Is the question better like this?

Comment: Are there anything showing up in the console? when you type `var g = new QRCode(document.getElementById("ticket-qrcode"), "ABC");` in the console, what happens? if you then access `g`, is it undefined or is there an instantiated object there?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker - Well, as you can read in the EDIT, I'm now trying to use angular-qrcode, but that doesn't work as expected and I'm not getting any errors with that. Because this question is now actually about two different things (QRCode.js and angular-qrcode) maybe it is a better idea to start a new question. What do you think?

Comment: It'd be better to edit your question down to one issue.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker - I edited the question down to just angular-qrcode. Thanks for the feedback. Another question; would you know why the bounty I put out today for this question has vanished? I lost the points, but I don't think they've been given to anyone else either. Did you cancel the bounty?

Comment: @kramer65 I can see that the bounty is still open on this question (+200 reputation).

Comment: @AleksanderBlomskøld - Yes, I can't really get to a computer right now to test your new code. I will test it in the morning and if it works I will be glad to award you the 200.. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Never access the DOM in the controller, use [directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) for that.

Instead of creating your own directive you might want to have a look at [Angular-qrcode](https://github.com/monospaced/angular-qrcode).

The short version of how to use this library is just this:

```
<qrcode data="{{url}}"></qrcode>
```

To get this to work you need to include both the [original qr-code generator](https://github.com/kazuhikoarase/qrcode-generator/tree/master/js) and the angular wrapper (angular-qrcode) scripts in your html. Also remember to add `'monospaced.qrcode'` as a module-dependency.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've been trying to implement that, but when simply paste this `<qrcode data="ABC"></qrcode>` into the partial (either in or outside the ng-repeat) I don't get anything result; no qr-code, no error in the console, nothing. I wanted to make a jsfiddle out of it, but I don't know how to load angular-qrcode into it. Could you help me a little bit more to get this to work?

Comment: I now forked the angular-phonecat tutorial and tried using angular-qrcode in there (commit here: https://github.com/kramer65/angular-phonecat/commit/6e686f49827c0992378d611bab68517c7bf3b6b0), but I really can't get it to work. Would you know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: @kramer65 I've updated my answer with a little bit more information. I've also forked your github repo and made it working with this commit: https://github.com/aleksabl/angular-phonecat/commit/1695e5e073e286eb044f4dd3acc83bb03fe5d629

Comment: Works like a charm. Stupid that I didn't realise that I had to also use qrcode-generator. Thanks a million! I can't award you the 200 points yet (I have to wait a couple more hours), but I will do so as soon as I can. I wish you a beautiful day!